# Cell comments modifying commands are extremely slow in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My question is a bit broad but I find this issue extremely interesting.

Sometimes I have to create/clear comments in Excel worksheets using VBA code like:

`Range(someRange).ClearComments`

or

`.Comment.Shape.Width = 200`

These actions take ridiculous amount of time (like 1 sec for each) in comparison to other complex calculations in my code.
I turn `automaticCalculations`, `screenUpdating` and `EnableEvents` **off** every time I execute the code but it doesn't seem to make a big difference. 
Any ideas on how to speed these actions up?
What does excel do during this commands that is so much time consuming?

Edit:
The macro runs on a sheet with a big amount of data (100x40,000 cells).
The execution however need only a small portion of this data.
I figured that execution on the same data part alone, taken to a new sheet works much faster.

Comment: My test: delete, create and set width of 100k comments - less than 14 seconds, so there is probably some problem with your worksheet or code.

Comment: Lets see the code,entire code

Comment: I doubt that my code will help to resolve the issue. It is too long to be helpful here. What I figured out however is that the issue happens when i work with a big (40,000 rows, 100 columns) filtered ranges. when i cut the same range for manipulation to another sheet it executes much faster....

Comment: As others have noted, you should provide at least an example of the code you are working with. It sounds like there is an issue on your end, and not with the way VBA is handling the comments themselves. I don't see any reason why Excel would take a second at a time to process comments.

Comment: Looping through a massive range like that will definitely cause performance issues.

Comment: So select an answer already

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem and found out that it could be the `Shape.AutoSize` property. When set to true Excel handles the Comment significantly slower. In my case only about 4 per second.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False`. Remember to set the `ScreenUpdating` property back to `True` when your macro ends.

If you're doing`Comment.Shape.Width` multiple times, 
use a `With Statement` to make VBA avoid unnecessary path qualification.

```
With  Comment.Shape
.Width
.Height
' More properties
End With
```

More on how to increase the speed of your macro [here](http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html).

This will increase the speed of your macro, however, if you're processing huge amount of data, you will notice little improvement. It is far better, then, to optimize your code.

Comment: I tried all these with no significant effect. Also, why does excel take more time to modify one comment than to change values for a range of more than 1000 cells?

Comment: Can you paste your code? I've dealt with comments in the past and I had no trouble with them.

Answer (score 0):

I used this example, it adds a cell comment in column A that refers to Column B, I had 1500 rows filled in column B and ran the code that took about, 4 seconds.

The Delete_Comment code was instant.

```
Sub Add_Comment()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))
    For Each c In Rng.Cells

        With c
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = False
            .Comment.Text c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Comment.Visible = False
            .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        End With

    Next c

End Sub


Sub Delete_Comment()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))
    Rng.ClearComments

End Sub
```